# Asset Bundles Unity не загружаются в билде под UWP

Tags: c#, unity3d, uwp

Работаю над приложением для Mixed Reality. Задача загружать сцены из интернета и загружать их соответственно. Дело в том, что в проекте работают все методы загрузки ассет бандлов. Все загружается и запускается, но в билде Visual Studio выкидывает NullReference на моменте загрузки. В билде работает только LoadFromFile, но этот же метод крашит Unity в проекте. Билд под UWP, ассет бандлы под WSAPlayer. Подскажите, где копать и что это может быть.

Answer (score 0):

> но в билде Visual Studio выкидывает NullReference на моменте загрузки.
>
> В билде работает только LoadFromFile, но этот же метод крашит Unity в проекте.

Нуллреф - довольно распространённая ошибка программы (чего уж таить - у самого такой грешок есть (>~<) ). Unity в дебаг-логе (Console) показывает, в каком скрипте произошла ошибка + вроде должен показать строчку ошибки.

Попробуй посмотреть, что может быть не так с твоим кодом. Лучше, конечно, подключить VS к Unity (знаешь, как делать отладку?), и потом смотреть значения переменных, нажимая F10 и переходя от строчки к строчке.

Скорее всего, у тебя какая-нибудь ошибка инициализации, т.е. забыл написать

```
yourList = new List<GameObject>();
```

или что-нибудь в роде этого. Но код никакой ты не предоставляешь, поэтому что-то конкретное ответить сложно.

Жду от тебя либо код, либо сообщение, что всё починил.